# Set-ADUser with PowerShell's ActiveDirectory Module: changing the user's OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I was wondering if it was possible to change the OU (organizational unit) of a user in ActiveDirectory using PowerShell.  I have a script that should update many of the fields.  I am using the Set-ADUser command to update, but I can't seem to find a flag that will allow me to update the OU.  Below is the the Set-ADUser command I am using currently.  The variables are set earlier in the script and shouldn't be relevant to the question.

```
set-ADUser -identity $samName -GivenName $firstName -Surname $lastName -Department $department -Description $description -Manager $manager -AccountExpirationDate $acctExp -Organization $org
```

I also have a script that creates users.  That script allows me to set the OU.  That leads me to believe that I could change the OU after creation.  Below is the command I use to create the user.  Again, the variables are set earlier in the script.

```
New-ADUser -Name $dName -SamAccountName $sam -GivenName $firstName -Surname $lastName -Path $OU -AccountPassword $passwd -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Department $department -Description $description -Manager $manager -Organization $org
```

If there is a flag for the Set-ADUser command that would be great, otherwise, any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the move-adobject:

```
Move-ADObject 'CN=myuser,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com' -TargetPath 'OU=mynewou,DC=mydomain,DC=com'
```

or

```
Get-ADUser $name| Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'OU=mynewou,DC=mydomain,DC=com'
```

Comment: Wonderful.  I was trying to find a Change-ADUser or something like that.  Move makes a lot more sense.  Thank you.

Comment: Minor nitpick - shouldn't the second command say `DC=mydomain` instead of `OU=mydomain`?

Comment: @CodyPoll Yes! Fixed. ;)